# Proving group properties of $G$, a set of $2 \times 2$ matrices with rational entries

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Let $G$ be the set of all $2 \times 2$ matrices whose entries are rational numbers and whose determinant is equal to $3^n$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer.

Prove that $G$ is a group with respect to the matrix multiplication.

Take $A,B \in G$. $A,B$ have rational entries, and we can see that the product of two matrices with rational entries is a matrix with rational entries. So $AB$ has rational entries. So if $A,B \in G, \: AB \in G$, hence $G$ is closed under multiplication.

Lastly we need to show that it contains inverses. Suppose $A \in G$, and let $B = A^{-1}$ be its inverse. Suppose $A=(a_{i,j}), B=(b_{i,j})$. We know that $AB=I$. We know that if $i \ne j$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{a_{i,k}b_{k,j}=0}$ and if $i=j$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n{a_{i,k}b_{k,i}}=1$. We can see these equations as linear equations where the $b_{i,j}$ are the variables and the $a_{i,j}$ are the coefficients. So we get that the ($b_{i,j}$) satisfy $n^2$ linear equations. To solve these equations we just need to
add them together and divide by the $a_{i,j}$. All of the coefficients are
rational numbers so we can see that the solutions to these equations
are rational as well. So the $b_{i,j}$ are rational. Thus the inverse of a
matrix with rational entries also has rational entries. So $B \in G$.
Hence $G$ is a group under matrix multiplication.

**Does that work? Should I include something about identity?**

---

Let $$H=\{A \in G \mid \det A = 9^m\ \text{for some nonnegative integer m} \}$$ Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

This means we need to show, $\forall h \in H, \: \forall g \in G$ that $ghg^{-1} \in H$.

**I am not sure the best way to go about this, thoughts?**

---

Describe the center of the group $G$.

This means we need to show $Z(G) =$ {$z \in G|\forall g \in G, \: zg=gz$}.
**I am not sure the best way to go about this, thoughts?**

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Find a $2\times 2$ matrix with rational entries and determinant $3$. Is the determinant of the inverse of the shape $3^n$, where $n\ge 0$?

**Remark:** If we replace $n$ a non-negative integer by $n$ is an integer, we indeed get a group. The problem with your proof is that you did not use the fact that the inverse of a group element must be a group element.

Comment: I have a matrix $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 2&1\\ 3&3 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ with $detA=3$, however, the determinant of the inverse is $3^{-1}$. So this condition is not always satisfied?

Comment: Isn't the whole last paragraph proving that the inverse of a group element is a group element?

Comment: Also, any suggestions on how to approach the other two parts?

Comment: Again, there is something wrong, maybe a translaion problem. The $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $9^m$ with $m\ge 0$ don't form a subgroup, they are not closed under inverse. But it certainly is true that if $h\in H$, then for any $g$ in $G$, we have $ghg^{-1}\in H$. This is because the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants: $\text{det}(ghg^{-1})=\text{det}(g)\text{det}(h)\frac{1}{\text{det}(g)}=\text{det}(h)$.

Comment: As to the last problem, the centre of this group is the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices which are $r$ times the identity matrix. So *equal* rationals down the main diagonal, $0$ elsewhere. Now that you know the answer, maybe you can prove the result.